# How to find if item is first in a column in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

If I have a table:

```
Person:  Action:   Location:
-------  --------  ---------
Alan     Pondered  Garden
Bob      Hesitated Stairs 
Carol    ACTED     Kitchen
Dave     ACTED     Kitchen
Eric     Slept     Kitchen
Alan     ACTED     Cellar
Bob      Slept     Cellar
Fred     ACTED     Cellar
```

..and want to find the first person who "ACTED" ***first*** in each room, how do I do this?

I'd like to do this within an existing query:

```
SELECT Person,
       Location,
       <CLEVER-CODE-HERE> as flg_First --BOOLEAN was first to ACT
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Person,Location
ORDER BY Person
```

Desired result would be:

```
Person: Location: flg_First:
------- --------- ----------
Alan    Cellar    TRUE
Alan    Garden    False
Bob     Cellar    False
Bob     Stairs    False
Carol   Kitchen   TRUE
Dave    Kitchen   False
Eric    Bedroom   False
Fred    Cellar    False
```

I'm hoping this maybe achievable (with a window function?) but how?

Comment: "want to find the first person" . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* tables, unless you have a column that specifically encodes the ordering.  Do you have such a column?

Comment: _First_, according to what? (Looks like person name.)

Comment: "First, according to what? (Looks like person name.) " - in each room, so therefore location.

2 Good answers below, one "modern", one more "classic" ;) - thanks Gordon and forpas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select m.person, m.location,
  case 
    when m.action = 'ACTED' and not exists (
      select 1 from my_table
      where action = m.action and location = m.location and rowid < m.rowid
    ) then 'TRUE'
    else 'False'
  end flg_First 
from my_table m
order by m.person, m.location
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmLauLKyqAqh6iz9wGJGgF/1).
You can do it also with `ROW_NUMBER()` with a composite sorting involving `action` and `rowid`:

```
select person, location,
  case 
    when action = 'ACTED' 
      and row_number() over (partition by location order by action <> 'ACTED', rowid) = 1 then 'TRUE'
    else 'False'
  end flg_First
from my_table
order by person, location
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmLauLKyqAqh6iz9wGJGgF/2).
Results:

```
| Person | Location | flg_First |
| ------ | -------- | --------- |
| Alan   | Cellar   | TRUE      |
| Alan   | Garden   | False     |
| Bob    | Cellar   | False     |
| Bob    | Stairs   | False     |
| Carol  | Kitchen  | TRUE      |
| Dave   | Kitchen  | False     |
| Eric   | Kitchen  | False     |
| Fred   | Cellar   | False     |
```

Comment: Thanks you for providing two approaches (and demos!).
Just as well because I'm using SQLiteStudio (v3.2.1) which doesn't support the partition approach (which is a shame as it would have been my preference), first approach works well TY.
1.Question: why SELECT 1 and not SELECT * in the subquery - is there a performance benefit here?
2. I muddied the waters with TRUE and False in my question, I just wanted to highlight the TRUEs, when in fact I just require SQLite true/false (0/1) - so the CASE can be dispensed with.
3. Can the implicit join going on here be rewritten as an explicit JOIN?

Comment: 1. There is no difference for the result if you use SELECT * instead of SELECT 1, and the same should apply for performance, but for this I'm not 100% sure, so test it. 2. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmLauLKyqAqh6iz9wGJGgF/3

Comment: 3. What do you mean?

Comment: action = m.action     in subquery made me think there is a join going on ("behind" the scenes), but guess this is just correlating main and subquery?

Comment: No, this is not a join. What it does is to check for each row of the table if there exists in the same table  a row with the same action and location and smaller rowid.

Comment: Sounds like a world of debate on the SELECT 1 vs SELECT * front, shouldn't affect performance but SELECT 1 is preferred from an auditing perspective. Quite like the SELECT NULL pattern here instead, we aren't actually selecting anything, just checking if it exists! :p Re: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/select-versus-select-1-when-using-exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200730/discussion-between-richard-plester-and-forpas).

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume that you have an ordering column, such as `rowid`, that specifies the ordering of the rows.

If so, one method uses `row_number()` with some conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when action <> 'ACTED' then 'false'
             when 1 = row_number() over (partition by location, action order by rowid)
             then 'true' 
             else 'false'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: Question on a style point, why 1 = expression rather than expression = 1 here? See this a lot in SQL, Just habit/style or does it have merit? Even notice Anthony Molinaro does it in the SQL Cookbook a lot!

Comment: @RichardPlester . . . So the value `1` is not at the end of a long line that needs to be scrolled to see it.  From my old programming days, this also prevented confusing in languages where `=` was for assignments . . . but that was allowed in conditional expressions (C-based languages are prone to the sort of error where `==` is mistyped as `=`).  You cannot assign to a constant, so that protects against that error.